# How do I wire a duplex outlet from a switch/outlet combo?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher, garbage-disposal

The power comes first through a switch/outlet combo and I need to it take further down to a duplex outlet. The switch will control half the outlet and the other half will always be hot. This is intended to control a garbage disposal (On - Off) from the counter top while the dishwasher stays powered.

Comment: Most built-in dishwashers are hard wired using boxes that are part of the unit rather than with plugs.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have power always on to a box that is downstream of a switch, you'll need to use 3-conductor cable between the switch and split the hot side of the outlet.

At the outlet, break off the tab on the hot side only between the top and bottom outlet.  Wire the red conductor to one of the hot screws, the black conductor to the other one, and then the white to the other side of the outlet.

At the switch/outlet, you'll need to wire the incoming black wire to one of the hot screws, and the outgoing black wire (to the 3 condutor cable) to the other hot screw.  The outgoing red wire (the one controlled by the switch) goes on the neutral side of the switch, and the incoming white wire gets wire-nutted together to the neutral side of the outlet along with the  outgoing white wire (from the 3 conductor cable)

Be sure to ground all outlets and switches as well.

[image]

<sub>With this setup the bottom outlet on the second receptacle, and the outlet on the combo device will always be hot. The top outlet on the second receptacle, will be controlled by the switch.</sub>

Comment: There is a good article with [wiring diagrams](http://www.ask-the-electrician.com/disposal-wiring-diagram.html) at [Ask the Electrician](http://www.ask-the-electrician.com)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please assist me in reversing the photo above with a catch? I have power to the outlet and want to add a combo switch after the outlet. Also, I want the combo switch to control power to the top of the outlet that power originates. Finally, keep constant power to both outlet bottoms. Thank you very much!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/175794)