# electrical combination outlet and switch wiring

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I have a combination wall plate with a switch on top and outlet on the bottom.  The switch controls the garbage disposal and the outlet is always on.  There are two black wires and one white.  One side of the combination plate has two screws that are near each other and the other side the screws are at the top and bottom. Can you help me wire it.  I tried once and blew the circuit breaker (and I think I blew the switch too).  Also, do I need to remove the fin in order to make it work?

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/15952/33) might be helpful.

Comment: Can you give the colors of the screws (black, silver, gold) along with their location; or better yet a pic?